# Websockets in django and phonegap

Tags: python, django, sockets, cordova, websocket

I am trying to finish a phonegap app with django as a backend. I want to implement web sockets in this app. To give a use case, there are an array of buttons that all the users can see, if one user makes any changes to the button (enable/disables) the change should be visible to other users as well. The way I am coin it right now is after every 3 seconds I am sending a call to the server weather the status of the button has changed and if yes I refresh the page. I believe there could be a better solution to this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://autobahn.ws/python/, more precisely WAMP implementation.
I think a pubsub pattern (http://wamp.ws/faq/#pubsub) is suitable for you.
Javascript mobile clients will be connected to your server to listen changes.
When one of users changes button, he will send request via websocket and other users, who was subscribed, will recieve these changes.

If you wish to publish events via django, you should use non-blocking stuff such as https://github.com/itamarst/crochet.

Comment: Yep. One note: using AutobahnJS on Cordova with Android works fine (we've done apps with that combo) - as long as the underlying WebView has WebSocket support - which means Android 4.4+ (where WebView is based on Chromium).